# How can I save my HTML5 canvas screen as a png image to a specific folder of my project with only pure javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is what I have found and used so far for saving the image. This function perfectly taking the screenshot and opens the image in a new window location. But I want to save the png image file to a specific folder of the project temporarily so that later on I can retrieve the image from that folder. 
This is my JS function:

```
function saveImage()
{
    var canvasScreen = document.getElementById("paintCanvas");
    var myImage; 
    if (canvasScreen.getContext) 
    {
         ctx = canvasScreen.getContext("2d");                
         myImage = canvasScreen.toDataURL("image/png");     
    }
    window.location.href = myImage;
}
```

This is the HTML part:

```
 <canvas id="paintCanvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
```

I have already tried FileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) but not succeeded. I have searched my solutions but came with nothing that works properly. I need this for HTML based mobile app. Please can anyone give me some clear idea or anything that you faced similar? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JavaScript does not have access to your local file system. It's all sandboxed for security reasons.

You can send it to server and invoke a save-as from there (as you can do on client side as well, except for in IE), or use one of the many APIs for things like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/) etc. (or make a custom native application for the platform) which you integrate for synchronization on your local system in advance.

There is no way around it unfortunately.